# How to save csv file in django model?

Tags: python, django, csv

This my model

```
class CSV(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    height = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    mass = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    hair_color = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    skin_color = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    eye_color = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    birth_year = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    homeworld = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    films = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    species = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    vehicles = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    starships = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    edited = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This my serializers

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class FileUploadSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    file = serializers.FileField()

class SaveFileSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = CSV
        fields = "__all__"
```

This my view

```
count = {'count': 0, "next_page": 1, 'dates': [],}

starwars = [count, ]

class PeopleView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = FileUploadSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        page = request.query_params.get('page', 1)
        if starwars[0]['next_page'] == int(page):
            url = f'https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page={page}'
            response = requests.get(url).json()
            starwars.append(response['results'])
            starwars[0]['count'] += 10
            starwars[0]['next_page'] += 1
            starwars[0]['dates'].append(datetime.today())
            with open('story.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                file.write(str(starwars[0]))
                file.write('\n')
                #csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=';')
                for i in range(1, len(starwars)):
                    for j in starwars[i]:
                        file.write(str(j))
                        file.write('\n')
            return Response(starwars, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response({"error": "Enter valid page"})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        file = serializer.validated_data['file']
        reader = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=2, header=None)
        for _, row in reader.iterrows():
            new_file = CSV(
                       name = row['name'],
                       height= row["height"],
                       mass= row["mass"],
                       hair_color= row["hair_color"],
                       skin_color= row["row"],
                       eye_color= row["eye_color"],
                       birth_year= row["birth_year"],
                       gender= row["gender"],
                       homeworld= row["homeworld"],
                       films= row["films"],
                       species= row["species"],
                       vehicles= row["vehicles"],
                       starships= row["starships"],
                       craeted= row["created"],
                       edited= row["edited"],
                       url= row["url"],
                       )
            new_file.save()
        return Response({"status": "success"},
                        status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

This is the file I get on request and write to csv.file
and at the same time I add my values there
{'count': 10, 'next_page': 2, 'dates': [datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 29, 12, 28, 19, 365395)]}

```
{'count': 10, 'next_page': 2, 'dates': [datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 29, 12, 28, 19, 365395)]}
{'name': 'Luke Skywalker', 'height': '172', 'mass': '77', 'hair_color': 'blond', 'skin_color': 'fair', 'eye_color': 'blue', 'birth_year': '19BBY', 'gender': 'male', 'homeworld': 'https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/', 'films': ['https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/3/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/'], 'species': [], 'vehicles': ['https://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/14/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/30/'], 'starships': ['https://swapi.dev/api/starships/12/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/starships/22/'], 'created': '2014-12-09T13:50:51.644000Z', 'edited': '2014-12-20T21:17:56.891000Z', 'url': 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/'}
{'name': 'C-3PO', 'height': '167', 'mass': '75', 'hair_color': 'n/a', 'skin_color': 'gold', 'eye_color': 'yellow', 'birth_year': '112BBY', 'gender': 'n/a', 'homeworld': 'https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/', 'films': ['https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/3/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/4/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/5/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/'], 'species': ['https://swapi.dev/api/species/2/'], 'vehicles': [], 'starships': [], 'created': '2014-12-10T15:10:51.357000Z', 'edited': '2014-12-20T21:17:50.309000Z', 'url': 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/2/'}
{'name': 'R2-D2', 'height': '96', 'mass': '32', 'hair_color': 'n/a', 'skin_color': 'white, blue', 'eye_color': 'red', 'birth_year': '33BBY', 'gender': 'n/a', 'homeworld': 'https://swapi.dev/api/planets/8/', 'films': ['https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/3/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/4/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/5/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/'], 'species': ['https://swapi.dev/api/species/2/'], 'vehicles': [], 'starships': [], 'created': '2014-12-10T15:11:50.376000Z', 'edited': '2014-12-20T21:17:50.311000Z', 'url': 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/3/'}
{'name': 'Darth Vader', 'height': '202', 'mass': '136', 'hair_color': 'none', 'skin_color': 'white', 'eye_color': 'yellow', 'birth_year': '41.9BBY', 'gender': 'male', 'homeworld': 'https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/', 'films': ['https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/3/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/'], 'species': [], 'vehicles': [], 'starships': ['https://swapi.dev/api/starships/13/'], 'created': '2014-12-10T15:18:20.704000Z', 'edited': '2014-12-20T21:17:50.313000Z', 'url': 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/4/'}
{'name': 'Leia Organa', 'height': '150', 'mass': '49', 'hair_color': 'brown', 'skin_color': 'light', 'eye_color': 'brown', 'birth_year': '19BBY', 'gender': 'female', 'homeworld': 'https://swapi.dev/api/planets/2/', 'films': ['https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/3/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/'], 'species': [], 'vehicles': ['https://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/30/'], 'starships': [], 'created': '2014-12-10T15:20:09.791000Z', 'edited': '2014-12-20T21:17:50.315000Z', 'url': 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/5/'}
{'name': 'Owen Lars', 'height': '178', 'mass': '120', 'hair_color': 'brown, grey', 'skin_color': 'light', 'eye_color': 'blue', 'birth_year': '52BBY', 'gender': 'male', 'homeworld': 'https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/', 'films': ['https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/5/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/'], 'species': [], 'vehicles': [], 'starships': [], 'created': '2014-12-10T15:52:14.024000Z', 'edited': '2014-12-20T21:17:50.317000Z', 'url': 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/6/'}
{'name': 'Beru Whitesun lars', 'height': '165', 'mass': '75', 'hair_color': 'brown', 'skin_color': 'light', 'eye_color': 'blue', 'birth_year': '47BBY', 'gender': 'female', 'homeworld': 'https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/', 'films': ['https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/5/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/'], 'species': [], 'vehicles': [], 'starships': [], 'created': '2014-12-10T15:53:41.121000Z', 'edited': '2014-12-20T21:17:50.319000Z', 'url': 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/7/'}
{'name': 'R5-D4', 'height': '97', 'mass': '32', 'hair_color': 'n/a', 'skin_color': 'white, red', 'eye_color': 'red', 'birth_year': 'unknown', 'gender': 'n/a', 'homeworld': 'https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/', 'films': ['https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/'], 'species': ['https://swapi.dev/api/species/2/'], 'vehicles': [], 'starships': [], 'created': '2014-12-10T15:57:50.959000Z', 'edited': '2014-12-20T21:17:50.321000Z', 'url': 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/8/'}
{'name': 'Biggs Darklighter', 'height': '183', 'mass': '84', 'hair_color': 'black', 'skin_color': 'light', 'eye_color': 'brown', 'birth_year': '24BBY', 'gender': 'male', 'homeworld': 'https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/', 'films': ['https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/'], 'species': [], 'vehicles': [], 'starships': ['https://swapi.dev/api/starships/12/'], 'created': '2014-12-10T15:59:50.509000Z', 'edited': '2014-12-20T21:17:50.323000Z', 'url': 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/9/'}
{'name': 'Obi-Wan Kenobi', 'height': '182', 'mass': '77', 'hair_color': 'auburn, white', 'skin_color': 'fair', 'eye_color': 'blue-gray', 'birth_year': '57BBY', 'gender': 'male', 'homeworld': 'https://swapi.dev/api/planets/20/', 'films': ['https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/3/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/4/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/5/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/'], 'species': [], 'vehicles': ['https://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/38/'], 'starships': ['https://swapi.dev/api/starships/48/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/starships/59/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/starships/64/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/starships/65/', 'https://swapi.dev/api/starships/74/'], 'created': '2014-12-10T16:16:29.192000Z', 'edited': '2014-12-20T21:17:50.325000Z', 'url': 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/10/'}
```

I got too many errors this week (example: pandas.errors.ParserError: Data tokenization error. Error C: Expected 21 fields on line 4, saw 22) I don’t understand anything how to upload this csv file to the database. Please write solution code

Comment: What is `pd` in view file?

Comment: @MaGaroo pd reads the file variable in which I put this cvs in json